# How can I 'warm up' the camera on an iOS device prior to use?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I'm currently using the ZBar SDK for scanning barcodes on iOS. However, when starting up the scanning process, there is a delay of about 5 or 6 seconds before the camera becomes active.

An alternative (commercial) SDK, RedLaser, has a method call 'prepareToScan' which powers up the camera; this is called a few seconds before the scanning (eg when the user selects the screen prior to scanning) and avoids the camera set-up delay.

I had a look at the `AVCaptureDevice` documentation, but cannot find anything that would allow me to do something equivalent, ie prepare the camera for use. Any idea how I could do that?

Comment: By start up delay, do you mean the time it takes for the camera to come into focus? When using the video camera (or the video preview from a still camera) via AVFoundation, the camera itself activates almost immediately in all of my applications here.

Comment: It's the delay between pressing the 'scan' button and the time the scan view is presented. The first time this is very noticeable, while on subsequent trials it's pretty much instantaneous. What I tried is to get hold of the `AVCaptureSession` (which ZBar exposes) and call `startRunning` on it. That seems to do the trick. It still takes time to come up, but the clock starts ticking before the button is pressed, ie if you wait a few seconds and then press the button it's instantaneous.

Comment: That sounds to me like some kind of internal warmup within ZBar itself, rather than something particular to the AVFoundation camera input. As I said, that seems to start instantly, but maybe they need to prime some data structures before processing takes place.